# Accessing object's elements of Multiple ArrayList in java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I cannot access Multiple `ArrayList` element. The code is given below and it cannot access the values 5 or 6. My IDE is not accepting the last statement of my code which is `System.out.println(specification.get(0).get(0).value);` How can I get the elements of an Object in `ArrayList` which is within an array list.

```
class Node {

    int value;
    boolean explored;

    Node(int v) {
        value = v;
        explored = false;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Board {

    ArrayList<ArrayList> specification;
    ArrayList<Node> speci_node;

    Board() {
        speci_node = new ArrayList<Node>(1);
        speci_node.add(new Node(5));
        speci_node.add(new Node(6));

        specification = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(1);
        specification.add(speci_node);
        System.out.print(specification.get(0).get(0).value);  // variable 'value' is not found error....
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: the IDE is not accepting the last statement. It is say variable 'value' is not found

Comment: Are both classes are in the same file? Or are they in different files and maybe different packages as well?

Comment: no, for understanding i have merge them here

Answer (score 3):

While @YCF_L's answer is correct, you could as well specify the generic type of the inner `ArrayList` to avoid the cast:

```
specification = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>(1);
```

Furthermore the `Node` and `Board` classes need to be in the same package, as the `value` member is package private and thus not accessible outside of the package of the `Node` class. But this already seems to be the case here...

Answer (score 1):

You should to cast your element like this :

```
System.out.print(( (Node) specification.get(0).get(0)).value);
//-----------------|-^^^-|-----------------------------------
```

This will return `5`

Comment: There's no need to cast if you declare the generic type correctly

Comment: it still a solution @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner my answer help the OP so why this down-vote?

Comment: mmmm @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner ok :)

Comment: Because of what I stated in my previous comment: there's no need to cast if the outer `ArrayList` is correctly declared. If you edit your question and clarify this point, I will gladly undo my downvote

Comment: My answer help the OP and it still a way to solve this problem, maybe the OP need it like this there are many solutions @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner ok you are free to make down-votes, i don't mind

Comment: @YCF_L I agree with you in that your answer helped the OP. However, your answer is not only for the OP, but also for everyone else who needs to solve a similar problem and comes to this question. And casting unnecessarily might be a solution for this particular case, but it's not a good solution for the general case, i.e. it might lead to an unexpected `ClassCastException`. Maybe I was too harsh with my downvote, that's why I explained my viewpoint with a comment.